# How to campture the text change event of a text control to call a function in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, events

I am very new to flex and have trouble capturing the text change event of my text control:

```
<mx:Text id="description" 
             text="" 
             textAlign="center" 
             fontSize="18" 
             click="_playSpeech()"   />
```

it's a click right now but i need it to be something like textChange="_playSpeech()" so it calls that function every time the text of the of that control changes.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are watching changes that the user enters in the textbox itself you should use the class *TextArea or TextInput* instead of *Text*. This allows you to listen to changes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            protected function onTextChangeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                trace("text has changed")
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <mx:TextArea id="description" 
             text="text to change goes here ..." 
             textAlign="center" 
             fontSize="18" 
             change="onTextChangeHandler(event)"   />

</s:Application>
```

If you are changing the text outside the textbox I would recommend you to make a bindable variable or a function that triggers the action you want to happen.

Comment: I looked at these. thanks guys but I am changing the text dynamically and they are not changed by the user.

Comment: Take a look at [Bindable] and ChangeWatcher. Or you could just make the text source a setter function and dispatch the change from that function.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to register on the change event like so (Notice I'm using TextInput and not Text):

```
<mx:TextInput id="description" text="" fontSize="18" change="_playSpeach()"/>
```

Comment: That's cool. But change only works if the user changes a text but I am changing the text dynamically within the code

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it within the code is by wrapping the text update into a function:

```
        protected function updateDescription(text:String):void
        {
            description.text=text;
            _playSearch();
        }
```

and then always call the function instead of immediately change the text field. Also prevents unnecessary use of events.